# MSBuild: Project not built when input file changed

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

In my project's *.csproj* file (using Visual Studio) I defined a Target with `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes, specifying a transform on the Outputs. The Target simply copies each input file into a folder called *dist*:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SourceFiles Include="**\*.src" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target
    Name="SourceFileTransform"
    BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
    Inputs="@(SourceFiles)"
    Outputs="@(SourceFiles -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist" />
</Target>
```

With this I'm expecting that due to incremental building my project should be built when any one of the input files had been changed, that is, when the input file's timestamp is later than its mapped output file.

In testing this, I delete the *dist* folder, perform "Clean Solution", and build the solution. As expected, the project is built, and my *source.src* file (in the project's folder) is copied into a new *dist* folder.

When I build again, the project doesn't build, as I get the following output from "Build":

```
Build started...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 10:48 AM and took 00,312 seconds ==========
```

All good. Now I edit my *source.src* file and do another build. However, I get the same build output ("0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date"). The project isn't built and the *dist\source.src* file isn't updated.

This doesn't make sense: *source.src* now has a later timestamp than *dist\source.src*, so since the transform specified in `Outputs=...` maps the *source.src* file to *dist\source.src* this should cause the project to be built.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Good odds that Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > SDK-Style projects > "Up to Date Checks" turned off makes a difference.

Comment: If you build from the command line instead of within Visual Studio, is the behavior different?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes! That was it. Will you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Just wait for a better answer.

Comment: @bgh Hi, you can take a look at my answer, just provide a general method to quick jump out of the dilemma when you encounter a strange behavior of VS next time. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Thanks! Though, I would first of all try to just set the "Up to Date Checks" setting to off.

Comment: @bgh Hi, I post the answer just to provide a general method that you can use when you encounter strange VS problems, and you can’t find the source of the problem the first time (even if you don’t know the reason, you can quickly jump out of the predicament and return to the default settings). Hans is experienced in this area so he can quickly point out specific problems, but next time you encounter another problem you may use my solution, I just share an idea. **I completely agree that Hans’ comment should be the solution to your problem**. You can remind Hans to post a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out deciding whether or not to build a project is a mechanism built into Visual Studio and is not done by MSBuild. Furthermore, it appears that in doing so Visual Studio does not take into account changes in the input files of targets.

As pointed out by @Hans Passant disabling the "Up to Date Checks" option (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > SDK-Style projects > "Up to Date Checks") overcomes this issue at the cost of building all projects all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans mentioned, the root cause of your situation comes from the Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > SDK-Style projects > "Up to Date Checks" turned off.

I just want to share a general solution with you if you encounter a similar strange issue next time.

The general handle method is to reset the settings of VS.

**1, First of all, export the settings of the current VS(because maybe you still need some previous settings.)**

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Export selected environment settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2, Then, use this command [/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022) to reset the settings of VS.**

Go to the root directory of your VS Tools. For example, the version of the VS on my side is "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) 17.5.4", so on my side the default path is:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE`

Open your command prompt via administrator(Make sure you open with administrator otherwise nothing will happen.)

cd to the above path, and then run:

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
devenv /ResetSettings
```

[image]

After that, the setting will be reset successfully:

[image]

Please notice that when reset all of the settings, do not use the UI to reset, it can't reset everything.